# Urgent treatment for Echeverias, in mid-winter

Tags: roots, rot, winter

My E. Purpusorum has begun to shrivel its bottom leaves and just by touching the plant it came-off. The roots seem to have died, but I still have a chance to root the stem. This species seems difficult to grow in my area, as I lost anoter E. Purpusorum last summer.

**My challenges** - Local climate and locally-used potting soil. First, I have a link to show you [the climate in my city](https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/israel/tel-aviv/climate). Values are average. Local nurseries potting soil is not sufficiently draining, but global warming has been on my side for a while. I potted-up few Echeverias into a better draining mix. Most have grown a bit and then flowered. I had to take advantage of the relatively warmer winter, because my pots sit in the open and are not protected from excess rain. My mix with much added Perlite seems to solve the problem.

**The sick plant** - It is now February, and temperatures are only now reminding me of true winter. I expect temperatuers to rise in March. My E. Purpusorum can be trimmed to take-off the dead roots and any parts of a rotten stem, if there is. **my question:** It is too cold and wet to make new roots?, Should I let the cuts callus and wait till mid-to-end of march to re-root it?

Comment: They should be hardy down to 0C, which looks OK from your chart. They do lose their bottom leaves as they grow, and you should remove them as they die to avoid fungus or rot infecting the plant. The problem might be the rain if they are kept outside. If water collects in the rosette of leaves, it can start to rot the plant. I wouldn't get obsessed about the soil quality - just make sure they don't get over-watered and there is no water remaining on the leaves. However small your living space is, you should have enough room to root a few leaves in small pots indoors, surely?

Comment: At the moment, I will try and re-root it. Since it's a summer grower, I will take leaf-cuttings later this year.